# ASP.NET MVC Selectable Tree/Grid/Search Data View

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on a web app in ASP.NET MVC 3 using the Razor HTML 5 engine and C#.  The client wants something pretty complex and I would like to know if there is any examples out on the web that might show me how to begin setting this up.  Here's what they are looking for:

I have a very large SQL database (25,000 rows).  They want to be able to select the data using three different views on the same page.

The first will be a tree and using similarities in certain columns of the table will be how the tree is broken in to sections.

The second will be a grid.  This will be just one entire list of the everything in the database that you can scroll through.  Of course there has to be some sort of virtual scrolling because loading 25,000 rows rather quickly isn't going to happen.

The third will be a search box where you can type in the code and select it that way.

All three of these need to be linked so that when you type a code in the search box it will select it in the grid and in the tree.  If you select it in the tree then it will be selected in the grid, and if you select it in the grid then it will be selected in the tree.

They also want me to remember the last selection when you navigate away and be able to type a code n on a different page and go directly to this page with the item you typed selected.  Therefore, I need to be able to use MVC's capabilities to establish a hyper link for every item in the list (I assume that would be the way to do this)

This is honestly the first time I've worked with ASP.net MVC and I feel like I may have bitten off more than I can chew with this project so any help would be greatly appreciated!

They would rather it if I didn't need to include any extra dll's so if there is a way to do this without third party tools that would be even better, but at this point I'm just looking for anything.

Comment: Is it a search feature that locates items on those 3 items? For example, if you type in a keyword, it automatically search and filters the 3 views? Can they provide example or mockup of what exactly do they want to achieve? Usually when clients asks for certain requirements, I ask them to provide a visual.
For the tree - do they want something like this? http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/index.php

Comment: It's not exactly a search.  The user will put in a specific code (CPT Medical coding code to be exact) and then that code will be selected in the tree and in the grid, so it won't filter it.  There will be a search function that filters results but it won't be on this page.  They call it a "jump to code" instead of a search.

Comment: That part of selecting a specific code is not specific to MVC IMO. It's hard to assess without having a visual of the requirements but there's tons of jQuery plugins out there that can help you with the tree view and data view. From the MVC point of view, there's nothing really complex that's going on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few random ideas/thoughts about this:

This is kind of a big project as your first MVC app - hopefully you have some experience with HTML/Javascript/jQuery since it's going to require a fair amount of glue code to make everything work together. There is no "here, do this" solution.

There are a bunch of different free/open source projects for treeviews and grids. I've used [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=5) for a number of projects - it works well. It has a decent API and is fairly configurable (although it may take some digging to find the example code you need).

For a treeview, you can try [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/). I haven't worked with it, though.

I'd suggest starting with just the treeview, or just the grid and get it working first. Then add the other control and get it working. Then add the search. Finally, I'd work on getting everything to work together.

To handle navigating to a specific selection, you can pull information off the query string from Javascript.

Realize that most of this is going to be happening in Javascript on the client side, not much server side.